# queue items appear in their original order followed by a copy of the queue items in reverse order

Tags: python-3.x, list, queue

*this is my program*

```
def mirror_queue(orig_queue):
    #backup_s = my_stack_module.Stack()
    length = len(orig_queue.items)
    counter = length
    while counter > 0 :
        item1 = orig_queue.dequeue()
        item2 = orig_queue.enqueue(item1)
        counter -=1
```

*it given an output follows [1,2,3] works for all lengths even an empty list. but i want a reversed version of it too.. for example [1,2,3,3,2,1]
i tried using .reverse()  but reversing the queue only [3,2,1]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing things from the front, adding to the back and that for the lenght of the list : this is just rotating things around, resulting in the same sequence.

You could do the same with `d.rotate(len(d))` - but the resulting list is the same order as before: `[1,2,3]-->[2,3,1]-->[3,1,2]-->[1,2,3]`.

Use

```
from collections import deque

def mirrDeque(d):
    c = deque(d)     #                     [1,2,3]
    c.reverse()      # reverse the copy    [3,2,1]
    c.extend(d)      # add the original    [3,2,1,1,2,3]
    c.rotate(len(d)) # rotate by len       [1,2,3,3,2,1]
    return c

k = deque([1,2,3,4])
print(mirrDeque(k))
```

Output:

```
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

Comment: Thank you. I know why my code isn't working. I made a queue1 = Queue() and enqueue everything their and then enqueue all the item to orig_queue .. now it works fine.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy, reverse it and concatenate.

```
myList = [1, 2, 3]
print(myList)  # [1, 2, 3]
listToReverse = myList.copy()
listToReverse.reverse()
myList += listToReverse
print(myList) # [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: `mylist = mylist + mylist[::-1]`

Comment: Hahaha I know that I was forgetting something nice about python!

Comment: Your code is really good.. but i dont know why it's giving me [3,2,1,1,2,3]

Comment: @mini looks like you are reversing `myList`, you can try the solution provided by @PatrickArtner.